# Do I need to warm my IP Address again?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-studio, deliverability

We run a journey in late May for IP warming, but we haven't run another journey since then. We are planning to run a journey this month and I'm wondering whether the IP warming we need is still valid or since it's been too long we'll have to do it again.

Thank you in advance

Edit: Some details. The journey run for 8 days, because the audience was small (around 39k), and at the end the delivery rate was 92.78% (34,932 people), with 2,718 bounces. We haven't run another journey since then and we are now planning to run a journey with an audience of 200k.

Edit: Contacted Help and they suggested doing the warmup from the beginning. Because of a time limit we just split the sends into multiple paths throughout the day, for multiple days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the little information you are sharing, it is impossible to provide you with a good answer. But, few points to consider:

1. Are you on a shared or private IP? If shared IP, you should not need to do another IP warming
2. What was the max weekly volume reached in May? What has it been since that time, on average? You can easily double your volume week-on-week. So if you have sent to 500.000 that week, and have been sending 200-300.000 emails per week since, you should also be fine without new IP warmup.
3. What is your distribution of emails across ISPs? Microsoft especially is quite harsh, and you should be cautious doing any rapid volume increase on their domains (Hotmail.com, Outlook.com, Live.com etc.)
4. You should keep an eye on your IP and domain reputation using [Google Postmaster tools](https://postmaster.google.com/) and [Microsoft's SNDS](https://postmaster.live.com/snds), to monitor their perception of you as a sender, and reduce email volumes if needed.
5. Using *[Email Performance for All Domains](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_email_performance_for_all_domains_report.htm&type=5)* report, you can see any differences between open rates across all your recipient domains. Should you see some whit half of the average open rate, it is an indication of your emails going to spam or being bounced (not all deliverability issues cause bounces).

You can check out this [article about deliverability monitoring](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/deliverability/deliverability-monitoring-in-marketing-cloud/) and [this one about IP warming](https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/deliverability/ip-warming-marketing-cloud/).

Comment: xD I'm deleting my answer

Comment: @RachidMamai this is not a competition, I wasn't intending to say your answer is not correct. The question is just not very good :-)

Comment: I didn't say it was a competition either, I just think I was too quick and neglected some essential parts in my answer that you covered in yours.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
The journey run for 8 days, because the audience was small (around 39k), and at the end the delivery rate was 92.78% (34,932 people), with 2,718 bounces. We haven't run another journey since then and we are now planning to run a journey with an audience of 200k.

Comment: @olsf you should keep sending above 100.000 emails per month, if you want to keep your dedicated IP warm. If you want to address your full audience of 200k, you will need to spend at least 4-5 weeks on warming up, as you need to do this from zero.